# How can I change the opacity of other menu items when this menu item is clicked?

Tags: jquery, click, opacity

I'm attempting to change the opacity of the other menu items in a navigation menu when one the menu items is clicked. I've currently tried this which breaks my jQuery code:

```
$("#navItem1").click(function(){
        $("#navItem2").css("opacity","0.3");  
        $("#navItem3").css("opacity","0.3");  
        $("#navItem4").css("opacity","0.3");  
        $("#navItem5").css("opacity","0.3");  
    });
```

Also on a side note - I've only done this for one menu item as an example, but is there a better way of coding this when I apply it to all of the 5 menu items.

Here's a jfiddle of how far I got: http://jsfiddle.net/9D33X/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".cmNavItem a").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('opacity','1')
           .closest('.cmNavItem')
           .siblings('.cmNavItem')
           .find('a')
           .css('opacity', '0.3')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9D33X/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9D33X/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cmNav li").click(function(){
        $("#cmNav li").not(this).css("opacity",.3);  
        $(this).css("opacity",1);   
    });

    $("#cmNavContainer").animate({left: 0}, 1000);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of this two options

1) Instead of:

```
    $("#navItem2").css("opacity","0.3");  
    $("#navItem3").css("opacity","0.3");  
    $("#navItem4").css("opacity","0.3");  
    $("#navItem5").css("opacity","0.3");
```

You could use

```
$("#navItem2,#navItem3,#navItem4,#navItem5").css("opacity","0.3");
```

2) Add class selector to your item menus

```
<ul>

<li class="items">Item1</li>
<li class="items">Item2</li>
<li class="items">Item3</li>
</lu>
```

and them

```
$(".items").click(function(){
$(this).css("opacity",0.3);
});
```